# Backup of a mysql database which is not running anymore

Tags: mysql

after a system failure, I have only limited access to the server. Question is, where does msyql store the database(s) and is it enough to just copy the files, or is anything else needed?

I think I already spotted the databases @ /var/lib/mysql ... is it enough to backup these files & re-use them with a newly created database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, it depends on your table type.

Check [this tutorial](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html) out.  It goes over different ways to get your database backups and also discusses methods on backing up for the future if you ever have this problem again.

Comment: The tutorial is from a good source, however it is important to supply an actual answer here. The post would become useless if that link 404's.

Comment: Here's the archive.org version of the tutorial: [MySQL manual backup tuto](https://web.archive.org/web/20191010154505/https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-methods.html) Saved with the Wayback machine Google Chrome extension available here [archive.org extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wayback-machine/fpnmgdkabkmnadcjpehmlllkndpkmiak) Use this extension to never again experience a 404 error!